# How to change the = character to "with the value"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have this from another question:

```
document.getElementById('value').innerHTML=listCookies()
function listCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
        aString += ' ' + theCookies[i-1] + "\n";
    }
    return aString;
}
```

It will say:

```
cookie=value
```

How can I make it like this:

```
cookie with the value 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function listCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 0 ; i < theCookies.length; i++) {
        aString += ' ' + theCookies[i].replace('=', ' with the value ') + "\n";
    }
    return aString;
}
```